# Does Keyup Event (for enter key) will work in Jquery for tablet

Tags: jquery, tablet, enter, keyup

In my application, I am calling one method when pressing the enter key in textbox,for that i have added the below code. This is working fine in PC, i wanted to know will this work in tablet as well. I don't have tablet, can someone pls help

```
$("#txtUsername").on('keyup', function (event) 
{
if (event.which == 13) {
$("#txtEmailID").focus();
}
});
```

Comment: https://caniuse.com/keyboardevent-key

Comment: Thanks Melancia. Is there any online tool for this so i can test my code to see the results as it is in tablet

Comment: As a personal preference, I would suggest [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/). You can do some testing using the free tier subscription.